# Sorting hash numbers in using matrices in python

Tags: python

I'm working on project to check for copies between two drives and I got stuck on sorting.

the output I have now is [ Filename, Hash, Location] in two list called drive1 and drive2

the output id'e like to end up with two text files with a list of the files that aren't in the other drive.

```
import os
import os.path
import hashlib

from os import path

drive1 = []
drive2 = []

file1 = input("Directory 1 location : ")
file2 = input("Directory 2 location : ")


AFile = open('skrar.txt','w')
AFile.close

def hash_file(filename):
 
    if path.isfile(filename) is False:
        pass 
 
    # make a hash object
    md5_h = hashlib.md5()
 
    # open file for reading in binary mode
    with open(filename,'rb') as file:
 
        # read file in chunks and update hash
        chunk = 0
        while chunk != b'':
            chunk = file.read(1024) 
            md5_h.update(chunk)
 
    # return the hex digest
    return md5_h.hexdigest()

with open('Drive1.txt', 'w') :
    AFile.write(hashlib.sha224(b"FILENAME").hexdigest())
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(file1):
        os.chdir(folderName)
        for filename in filenames: 
            AFile.write(filename+";"+hash_file(filename)+";"+os.getcwd()+";"+os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename)+'\n')

with open('Drive2.txt', 'w') :
    AFile.write(hashlib.sha224(b"FILENAME").hexdigest())
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(file2):
        os.chdir(folderName)
        for filename in filenames: 
            AFile.write(filename+";"+hash_file(filename)+";"+os.getcwd()+";"+os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename)+'\n')


with open('Drive1.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        drive1.append(line.split(";"))

with open('Drive2.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        drive2.append(line.split(";"))
```

I'm not sure how to go about this maybe I should use dictionaries?

Comment: If you just write two comma-separated files with "path,filename,hash", you can use `sort` and `diff` to show the differences to you.  BTW, you want `with open('Drive1.txt'), 'w') as AFile:` .  You forgot to assign it to the name.

Comment: Do you have any idea how long it's going to take to read every byte of every file on your disks?

Comment: Im not sure but one of the drives is about 650GB of family photos and i tried it with 12GB and it was running for about an half hour. but time isn't an issue i have a raspberry pi set-up i can leave on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, both `drive1` and `drive2` contain are lists of lists with length 3. The simplest approach would be the following:

```py
# filter() creates a new list with the files in the opposite drive removed
files_only_in_drive1 = filter(lambda x: x not in drive2, drive1)
files_only_in_drive2 = filter(lambda x: x not in drive1, drive2)
```

This isn't the fastest solution (since search in an unordered list takes linear time). A more performant solution would take advantage of hashing and the set difference operator:

```py
# Use tuple() for hashability.
drive1_file_set = set([tuple(file) for file in drive1])
drive2_file_set = set([tuple(file) for file in drive2])

# Now, remove files that are in the other drive using the set difference operator. In case it is necessary, I've added extra syntax to transform the 3-tuples to lists, and to cast the set back into a list.
files_only_in_drive_1 = [list(file) for file in drive1_file_set.difference(drive2_file_set)]
files_only_in_drive_2 = [list(file) for file in drive2_file_set.difference(drive1_file_set)]
```